# Create a point-to-point comm between a smartphone app and a PC app

Tags: android, iphone, windows, sockets, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows 8 Desktop application with C#, Visual Studio 2012 and .NET Framework 4.5.

This application can share data with smartphone(iPhone, Android or Windows Phone 8). PC running the app and smartphones will be on the same local network.

I want to do this:

- Register a smartphone device to a user in the app.
- Send data from the app to the device, and receive data from the device to the app.

**How can I do this? Using sockets?**

Answer (score -1):

Your goal can be achieved using sockets, yes.

Everything else will depend on a protocol that (I assume) you will create.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I will create my own protocol.